# when adding 2+ buttons to east layout, only 1 shows

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager

When adding 2+ buttons to east layout, only 1 shows. I am trying to test a layout that uses tabbed panes. For some reason when I try to add multiple buttons to the east region, it only shows 1 button. It just so happens the button displayed is the last one added to the east region, the rest are ignored. I am thinking maybe they are just hidden underneath the last button.

```
public void createPage1()
    {
        {
            panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

            panel1.add( new JButton( "North" ), BorderLayout.EAST );
            panel1.add( new JButton( "South" ), BorderLayout.EAST );
            panel1.add( new JButton( "East" ), BorderLayout.EAST );
            panel1.add( new JButton( "West" ), BorderLayout.EAST );
            panel1.add( new JButton( "Center" ), BorderLayout.EAST );
        }
    }
```

Comment: You realize you're adding all to EAST right ?

Comment: See also the [nested layout example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5621338/how-to-add-jtable-in-jpanel/5630271#5630271) for an illustration how you can nest layouts, which you will need to use if you want to add multiple buttons in the EAST

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I dont know, how you want your UI to look like, but try it this way:

```
public void createPage1() {
    //This will be the main panel. 
    //We are going to put several buttons only in the "EAST" part of it.

    panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

    //We create a sub-panel. Notice, that we don't use any layout-manager,
    //Because we want it to use the default FlowLayout
    JPanel subPanel = new JPanel();

    subPanel.add( new JButton( "1" ));
    subPanel.add( new JButton( "2" ));
    subPanel.add( new JButton( "3" ));

    //Now we simply add it to your main panel.
    panel1.add(subPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
}
```

Comment: I think I see what you did there! It is what Recursed mentioned as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

`BorderLayout` only allows one component per section. If you want to keep `BorderLayout`, but have 2+ buttons, I suggest first putting each of those buttons into a `JPanel` and then putting that `JPanel` into the east slot.

However, there are probably much better layout choices for you. You also mention tabs, which there is already `JTabbedPane` for.

Check out the different [`LayoutManagers`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), and try to figure out which one is right for you.

Answer (score 4):

**1.** The **default layout for JFrame** is `BorderLayout`, and it has East, West , North , South, and Center area, out of which Center is the default if positioning is not mentioned.

**2.** Now **each section/area can hold only one widget** (ie. swing component).

**3.** You will have this **done in much better way by using** `Group Layout`, which was developed by NetBeans team in 2005, use **Windows Builder Pro, now free from google.**

**4.** But **if you still want to go with the BorderLayout**, i will suggest you to use `JPanel` on the `content pane` of the `JFrame` to **add Buttons in the manner you want......**